# How validate multiple input when a save button is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I'd be happier if someone could analyze the following code and help me out. It's only the first condition that is validated but data is able to save even if the staffId is incorrect.

```
Try
    If rbnMale.Checked = True Then
        Sex = "M"
    Else
        Sex = "F"
    End If
    photo = "k"
    If txtStaffID.Text.Length < 6 Or txtStaffID.Text.Length > 6 Then
        lblStError.Text = "Please StaffID is not a six-digit integer"
        lblErrorMsges.Text = "At least one data validation error occured on this form. Please see the specific error messages."
        If txtName.Text.Length > 25 Then
            lblNameErr.Text = " Name should not exceed 25 characters"
            lblErrorMsges.Text = "At least one data validation error occured on this form. Please see the specific error messages."
                Else
        qry = "Insert into StaffDetails.Staff(StaffID,EmployeeName,SSN,Day,Month,Year,Sex,Qualifications,Rank,Responsibility,ApDay,ApMonth,ApYear,RegNumber,Phone,Email,Status,Photo)values(@StaffID,@EmployeeName,@SSN,@Day,@Month,@Year,@Sex,@Qualifications,@Rank,@Responsibility,@ApDay,@ApMonth,@ApYear,@RegNumber,@Phone,@Email,@Status,@Photo)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StaffID", Val(txtStaffID.Text)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@EmployeeName", txtName.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SSN", txtSsNumber.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Day", cboDay.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Month", cboMonth.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Year", txtYear.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Sex", Sex))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Qualifications", txtQualifications.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Rank", txtRank.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Responsibility", txtRespons.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ApDay", cboApDay.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ApMonth", cboApMonth.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ApYear", txtApYear.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RegNumber", txtRegdNum.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Phone", txtPhone.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Email", txtEmail.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Status", cboStatus.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Photo", img))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Record successfully saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        btnSave.Enabled = False
    End If
End If
    Showgrid()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a nested If statement, so it will still check the second condition and if it passes still save your Record. I would do something like this with a boolean flag to indicate an error.

Something like this:

```
Dim bError As Boolean
Try
    If rbnMale.Checked = True Then
        Sex = "M"
    Else
        Sex = "F"
    End If
    photo = "k"
    If txtStaffID.Text.Length < 6 Or txtStaffID.Text.Length > 6 Then
        lblStError.Text = "Please StaffID is not a six-digit integer"
        lblErrorMsges.Text = "At least one data validation error occured on this form. Please see the specific error messages."
        bError = True
    End If

    If txtName.Text.Length > 25 Then
        lblNameErr.Text = " Name should not exceed 25 characters"
        lblErrorMsges.Text = "At least one data validation error occured on this form. Please see the specific error messages."
        bError = True
    End If

    If Not bError Then
        qry = "Insert into StaffDetails.Staff(StaffID,EmployeeName,SSN,Day,Month,Year,Sex,Qualifications,Rank,Responsibility,ApDay,ApMonth,ApYear,RegNumber,Phone,Email,Status,Photo)values(@StaffID,@EmployeeName,@SSN,@Day,@Month,@Year,@Sex,@Qualifications,@Rank,@Responsibility,@ApDay,@ApMonth,@ApYear,@RegNumber,@Phone,@Email,@Status,@Photo)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StaffID", Val(txtStaffID.Text)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@EmployeeName", txtName.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SSN", txtSsNumber.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Day", cboDay.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Month", cboMonth.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Year", txtYear.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Sex", Sex))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Qualifications", txtQualifications.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Rank", txtRank.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Responsibility", txtRespons.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ApDay", cboApDay.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ApMonth", cboApMonth.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ApYear", txtApYear.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RegNumber", txtRegdNum.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Phone", txtPhone.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Email", txtEmail.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Status", cboStatus.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Photo", img))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Record successfully saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        btnSave.Enabled = False
    End If
    Showgrid()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Pls try to edit my code to suit what you mean exactly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm so much grateful to you. God bless you.

Comment: @Akaglo Glad to be of help, same to you.